# Convert XML like format to CSV in Perl

Tags: xml, csv, perl, grep

So, I have a file that looks like this:

```
random stuff in the beginning...

 <component>
   <name>bob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bob_secondbob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bam</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>
```

etc...

And, I want to just have it as a CSV like this:

```
name,age,country
bob,7,Great_Britain
bob_secondbob,7,Great_Britain
bam,7,Great_Britain
```

So I was wondering how would I go about doing this?

So my current code has the word like `bob` and `bam`, so i have been greping for it like this and using sed to just get the values:

```
grep -A4 "<component>" $file | grep -A4 "<name>$bob.*</name>" | grep "<name>" 
grep -A4 "<component>" $file | grep -A4 "<name>$bob.*</name>" | grep "<age>"
grep -A4 "<component>" $file | grep -A4 "<name>$bob.*</name>" | grep "<country>"

etc...
```

Where the variable `$bob` is `"bob"`;

But the problem is that there are 2 instances of `bob.*` and I don't know how to separate them so I can print them out...

I looked at XML modules but this file isn't fully XML so I cant use that...

Like `bam` would be easy to print out by grepping it like that, but if there are multiple instances of `bob.*` where I need both of them, idk how to print it out properly because grep would return multiple results.

Any suggestion as to how i might go about this?

Comment: "Grep" is probably NOT the way to go.  I would suggest writing a short script or program, using a language that has a good XML library.  Perl (one of your tags) fits the bill.  I'd 1) Get [Perl LibXML](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/), 2) Parse your XML file, a "<component>" element at a time, 3) write your .CSV, a line at a time.

Comment: "_this file isn't fully XML_" -- (1) what precisely does that mean?  How far off is it?  (2) If it can't be done with a library then you're down to regex, and what you show isn't hard at all to parse.  The problem, of course, is that any teeny-tiny change in the future, or in another file, may require you to rewrite regex (or may quietly introduce bugs)

Comment: If your file is actually XML, that "random stuff" needs to be present so your sample data is valid XML.

Comment: @Shawn I take it that they _don't_ have XML altogether, by the title and a statement in text. But i agree that it'd be better to _make it_ proper XML and use library :)

Comment: I would read the file line by line, copying or modifying each line as necessary to create an output that is well-formed XML; and then process the XML using standard techniques like XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: Re "*I looked at XML modules but this file isn't fully XML*", All XML libraries I know accept XML from strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly stated that the "*file isn't fully XML*" and that XML libraries can't be used.  Bummer :(

Then this is parsed using regex. Remember that then one has to always keep an eye on input files to see whether their format changed; even a smallest change can easily throw off a regex, causing the program breakdown at best or, much worse, a quiet bug.<sup>†</sup>

The shown format is easy to parse.  Here's a basic take, parsing the XML-like `component` section for any tags and their values, then printing for a given set of actual tags in needed order.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $section_name = 'component';   # XML-like section to parse
my @tags = qw(name age country);  # given tags and their order

my (%record, $in_XML);

while (<>) {
    if    (/^\s*<$section_name>\s*$/)   { $in_XML = 1 }
    elsif (/^\s*<\/$section_name>\s*$/) { $in_XML = 0 } 
    
    if ( $in_XML and m{<([^<]+)> ([^<]+) </\g{1}>}x ) { 
        push @{$record{$1}}, $2; 
    }   
}

# Print out CSV-style output, with given tags
say join ',', @tags;
for my $i (0..$#{$record{$tags[0]}}) { 
    say join ',', map { $record{$_}->[$i] } @tags;
}
```

A few assumptions are made about tags. Some important ones: each tag-pair is on one line; all tag names are unique. If these don't hold the code need be adjusted, what can be done but would need some work.

On top of matching the XML-like opening and closing tag-pair, `<tagname>...</tagname>`, I've also added a flag for when the processing *is* inside a `component` section. Testing the flag inside the `if` condition allows for other processing outside of XML, otherwise we could have `next if not $in_XML;` before the `if` condition.  This whole business may be unnecessary if there is no chance for an accidental XML-like tag-pair elsewhere in text.

Note that one doesn't *have to* specify and use `@tags` but can print for tags as found in the file, which are `my @tags = keys %record`, if that is acceptable and if order doesn't matter.

Please add tests of whether those tags and their values are indeed what one expects. Realistic input files tend to occasionally have missing or unexpected parts.

---

<sup>†</sup> It'd be far better to remedy the "*isn't fully XML*" (make it XML) and use a library, if possible.

Comment: You could extract the XML pretty much the way you are already doing and use a parser on that.

Comment: @ikegami Right, and I considered it (that was my initial reason for `$in_XML` flag). I went this way since I don't know their data and how XML-impaired it is, in which case piecemeal-wise XML processing could confuse (or not work for some minor XML violation).  Now there's your proper XML way (with yet more goodies :) so all is well :)

Answer (score 1):

Input data read sequentially, once we come across `<component>` it indicates data follow.

Now we start parse data until we read `</component>` into hash and then push result into an array.

Once whole file processed, output keys of the hash as *header* and values of data hash for each element by join with `,`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @data;
my @fields = qw/name age country/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    if( /<component>/ ) {
        my $component;
        while( <DATA> ) {
            last if /<\/component>/;
            $component->{$1} = $2 if /^\s+<(.+?)>(.*?)</;
        }
        push @data, $component;
    }
}

say join ',', @fields;
say join ',', $_->@{@fields} for @data;

__DATA__


 <component>
   <name>bob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bob_secondbob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bam</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>
```

Second variant with [match range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6#How-can-I-pull-out-lines-between-two-patterns-that-are-themselves-on-different-lines?) and [named capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Named-backreferences)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(@data,%component);
my @fields = qw/name age country/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /<component>/../<\/component>/ ) {
        $component{$+{tag}} = $+{val} if m!<(?<tag>.+?)>(?<val>.*?)</\g{tag}>!;
        if( /<\/component>/ ) {
            my %hash = %component;
            push @data, \%hash;
            %component = ();        
        }
    }
}

say join ',', @fields;
say join ',', $_->@{@fields} for @data;

__DATA__


 <component>
   <name>bob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bob_secondbob</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>

 <component>
   <name>bam</name>
   <age>7</age>
   <country>Great_Britain</country>
 </component>
```

Output

```
name,age,country
bob,7,Great_Britain
bob_secondbob,7,Great_Britain
bam,7,Great_Britain
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still use a proper XML parser. It will be *faster*, *simpler*, *less error-prone*, *more readable*, *more maintainable*, and more. Simply extract the XML bits from the file and use the normal approach from there.

For all the same reasons, use a proper CSV generator instead of rolling out your own.

```perl
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );
use XML::LibXML  qw( );

my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new()
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2, binary => 1 });

$csv->say(\*STDOUT, [qw( name age country )]);

my $in_xml = 0;
my $xml;
while (
   $in_xml ||= /<component\b/;
   $xml .= $_ if $in_xml;
   if (/<\/component\b/) {
      my $doc = $xml_parser->parse_string($xml);
      my $name    = $doc->findvalue("/component/name");
      my $age     = $doc->findvalue("/component/age");
      my $country = $doc->findvalue("/component/country");
      $csv->say(\*STDOUT, [ $name, $age, $country ]);

      $in_xml = 0;
      $xml = undef;
   }
}
```

Alternative way to parse the XML:

```perl
my $doc = $xml_parser->parse_string($xml);
my %rec;
$rec{ $_->nodeName } = $_->textContent()
   for $doc->findnodes("/component/*");

$csv->say(\*STDOUT, [ @rec{qw( name age country )} ]);
```